# Создание sitemap

Tags: xml

Создаю XML карту сайта, но залив на сервер файл, получаю ошибку: файл отказывается принимать строку, в которой имеется такого рода ссылка `index.php?option=content&task=view&id=468`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

&, >, < - в xml нужно заменять на эквивалент. Например & - &amp;(с точко-запятой обязательно)

Answer (score 0):

```
urlencode($link)
```